# Missing enum values when compiling with dwarf

Tags: gcc, enums, objdump, dwarf

I'm compiling a simple C++ source file with some enum types declared in it (in the source file, not in an header file). I'm building it with GCC 4.9.2 and DWARF2 debug format.
After building it, i want to parse the enum values from the object file using objdump (objdump -W pubsym.o), but they are not included in the object file.

Example (pubsym.cpp):
...
enum Type_A { Value_A = 10 };
...

When I compile it with STABS debug format, the enums are included in the object file.
Am I missing some compile switch or something?

Comment: Is the type actually used?  GCC tends to omit unused things from debug info.

Comment: Thanks Tom.No, the enum isn't used in the code. I only need the enum value to read its value from the pubsym.o file for the link process (with objdump). Do you think there is a way to force GCC to write the value in the debug info (like when compiling with STABS)?

Comment: Try `-fno-eliminate-unused-debug-types`